# No need Facebook second time login, only once

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, chat, facebook-login

We are developing a Social Chatting Application, we are currently on Research Phase, and I need your help and valuable suggestions.

**Our Application features:**

A user sign up/Sign in our web Application from Facebook account, there will be our Facebook application in his Facebook account linked to our web application.

**Problem**

The problem we are facing is that we want whenever any user signup in our web application first time all the information like his Facebook friends, chat list, messages etc comes from his Facebook account to our web application.

We want that next time when same user sign in our web application he should not need to verify again all chat list, messages etc. he should only put his registration user name and password (our web application), and his Facebook chats, messages should come.

1)  No need Facebook second time login, only one time

2)  Application should be linked to his Facebook account forever, whenever he want.

So how this could be?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) No need Facebook second time login , ONLY ONE TIME

That depends on the user obviously. When the user logouts form the facebook in the browser, the facebook session will be ended, and the user have to login again. Until then, the user will be logged-in by itself- you just have to handle the code just so.

Eg: If using the javascript SDK,

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
    {
        if (response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            //var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            proceed();
        } 
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
          FB.login();
        } 
        else 
        {
          FB.login();
        }
      });
```

> 2) Application should be linked to his Facebook account forever, whenever he want.

Of course he will be until he deletes the App from his app settings.

I would suggest you to go through the basics of the facebook api once.